# Solvent for reaction mixture

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis, solvents

I'm looking for some suitable solvent for ether cleavage of Guaiacol (o-Methoxyphenol) using aluminium triiodide ($\ce{AlI3}$) with $\ce{DMSO}$. The original paper calls for using hot acetonitrile as a solvent, but I wonder what might be the alternatives. The ideal solvent would be some solvent with only mild toxicity.

What hydrocarbon solvents are a suitable replacement for this preparation?

Comment: Would you provide the original reference for reader's benefit?

Comment: Can't seem to find the original article, but this seems to have the same point. (https://www.x-mol.com/paper/833347) Similarly here the article discusses one-pot preparation using cyclohexane as a solvent. (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/slct.201803469) Do you think toluene might be suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aluminium iodide ($\ce{AlI3}$) is first introduced in 1984 as an easily accessible, a highly regioselective versatile ether-cleaving reagent with novel cleavage pattern (Ref.1). Application of $\ce{AlI3}$ in organic synthesis has been reviewed (Ref.2) and it seems like acetonitrile is the best solvent to be used in catechol ether demethylation (*e.g.*, 2-methoxyphenol or 1,2-dimethoxybenzene).

For example, recent article discussed an one‐Pot cleavage of aryl alkyl ethers by aluminum and iodine in Acetonitrile (Ref.3). Their proposed mechanism for the cleavage is depicted in following diagram:

[image: Cleaving mechanism by AlI3]

Accordingly, since it needs acid work-up for final product, I'd suggest you may use acetonitrile as the solvent of reaction, and use your solvent of choice to extract the final product from aqueous work-out.

If you are not happy with that, you may use either carbon disulfide ($\ce{CS2}$), which is also toxic, or toluene (their are references have been in literature using benzene as a solvent with mixed results) (Ref.2). Use of $\ce{CS2}$ is applied for specific reactions such as substrates having allyl functionality. Yet, it should work with simple compound as yours.

I'm little curious of your intend to use non-toxic solvent in the reaction since DMSO is also toxic in certain concentrations. In that case, you may use solvent-free conditions (you need to use enough DMSO for convenience, which is not critical according to the mechanism)(Ref.4).

**Note:** Cyclohexane is not a suitable reagent for this reaction, although it was involved in some publications (Ref.3). For example, when demethylation of eugenol reaction has bee done in acetonitrile at $\pu{80 ^\circ C}$ for $\pu{18 h}$, hydroxychavicol was achieved in 78%. However, when the reaction was run in cyclohexane under identical condition, no hydroxychavicol was achieved.

---

**References:**

1. M. Vivekananda Bhatt, J. Ramesh Babu, "New reagents 3: aluminium iodide - a highly regioselective ether-cleaving reagent with novel cleavage pattern," *Tetrahedron Letters* **1984**, *25(32)*, 3497-3500 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(01)91058-5).
2. Juan Tian, Dayong Sang, "Application of aluminum triiodide in organic synthesis," *ARKIVOC* **2015**, *(vi)*, 446-493 (http://dx.doi.org/10.3998/ark.5550190.p009.309).
3. Juan Tian, Huaxin Yue, Pengtao Yang, Dayong Sang, "One‐Pot Cleavage of Aryl Alkyl Ethers by Aluminum and Iodine in Acetonitrile," *Chemistry SELECT* **2019**, *4(1)*, 38-41 (https://doi.org/10.1002/slct.201803469).
4. Mehran Ghiaci, Jila Asghari, "Dealkylation of Alkyl and Aryl Ethers with $\ce{AlCl3 - NaI}$ in the Absence of Solvent," *Synthetic Communications* **1999**, *29(6)*, 973-979 (https://doi.org/10.1080/00397919908086060).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a few questions. 

Why cyclohexane is not a suitable solvent in this case?
Do you think toluene or benzene might work with allyl catechol ethers? That could be interesting.

As for the non-toxic solvents, it's out of curiosity and for the sake of convenience.
I wouldn't regard DMSO as a toxic or hazardous solvent since it's LD50 is twice that of ethanol and almost three times that of ethyl acetate.

Comment: 1) There was a publication, which states that reaction in cyclohexane has given least conversion among solvents used; 2) toluene  or benzene can be used with allyl catechol ethers, but should be careful with temperatures, since substrate is susceptible to undergo Cleisen rearrangement at high temp; I'm ok with DMSO reaction but still think it is toxic to humans. :-)

Comment: I edited the last paragraph to give the literature reference for cyclohexane use.

Comment: 1) I agree it's not suitable for one-pot preparation when everything is mixed together. It might be because iodine forms charge transfer complex with ether and it prevents the formation of AlI3 thus failing to produce the desired product. So My thought was to wait for AlIO to form (cyclohexane+Al+I2+DMSO) and then add dropwise allyl catechol ether of choice. 
2) One study achieved very good yield in 85%+ range with RT, so I'm going to try this way. Thanks for heads-up ;)